# overflow in swift (Int64)

Tags: swift, algorithm

Hi i have a func it counts the number of palindromes (using hash) in a row
and then input = long string i get overflow

```
    class palindrome {

    var string: String
    var str: [Character]
    var prefixHash: [Int64]
    var suffixHash: [Int64]
    var powArray: [Int64]
    var oddCount: [Int]
    var evenCount: [Int]
    var simpleBase: Int64 { return 21 }

    init(string: String) {
        self.string = string
        self.str = Array(string.characters)
        self.prefixHash = [Int64](repeating: 0, count: str.count)
        self.suffixHash = [Int64](repeating: 0, count: str.count)
        self.powArray = [Int64](repeating: 0, count: str.count)
        self.oddCount = [Int](repeating: 0, count: str.count)
        self.evenCount = [Int](repeating: 0, count: str.count)
        countPow()
    }


    func countPow() {
        powArray[0] = 1
        var i = 1
        while i < str.count {
            powArray[i] = powArray[i-1] &* simpleBase
            if powArray[i] < 0 {
                powArray[i] *= -1
            }
            i+=1
        }
    }

    func getHashForSubStr(left: Int, right: Int) -> Int64 {
        var result = prefixHash[right]

        if left > 0 {
            result = result - prefixHash[left-1]
        }

        return result
    }

    func getRevHashForSubStr(left: Int, right: Int) -> Int64 {
        var result = suffixHash[left]

        if right < suffixHash.count - 1 {
            result = result - suffixHash[right+1]

        }
        return result
    }

    func countPrefixHash() {
        prefixHash[0] = str[0].unicodeScalarCodePoint()
        var i = 1
        while i < str.count {
            prefixHash[i] = prefixHash[i-1] &+ (str[i].unicodeScalarCodePoint() &* powArray[i])
            if prefixHash[i] < 0 {
                prefixHash[i] *= -1
            }
            i+=1
        }

    }

    func countSuffixHash() {
        suffixHash[suffixHash.count-1] = str[str.count-1].unicodeScalarCodePoint()
        var i = str.count-2
        var x = 1
        while i >= 0 {
            suffixHash[i] = suffixHash[i+1] &+ (str[i].unicodeScalarCodePoint() &* powArray[x])
            if suffixHash[i] < 0 {
                suffixHash[i] *= -1
            }
            x+=1
            i-=1
        }

    }

    func isPalindrome(left: Int, right: Int) -> Bool {
        var first = getHashForSubStr(left: left, right: right) &* powArray[prefixHash.count - right - 1]
        var second = getRevHashForSubStr(left: left, right: right) &* powArray[left]

        return first == second
    }

    func countOdd() {
        var i = 0
        while i < oddCount.count {
            var left = 1
            var right = min(i+1, oddCount.count-i)
            while left <= right {
                let mid = (left+right)/2
                if isPalindrome(left: i-mid+1, right: i+mid-1) {
                    oddCount[i] = mid
                    left = mid + 1
                } else {
                    right = mid - 1
                }
            }
            i+=1
        }
    }

    func countEven() {
        var i = 0
        while i < evenCount.count {
            var left = 1
            var right = min(i, evenCount.count-i)
            while left <= right {
                let mid = (left+right)/2
                if isPalindrome(left: i-mid, right: i+mid-1) {
                    evenCount[i] = mid
                    left = mid + 1
                } else {
                    right = mid - 1
                }
            }
            i+=1
        }
    }
}




func answer(str: String) -> Int {
    let test = palindrome(string: str)
    let count = str.characters.count
    test.powArray
    test.countPrefixHash()
    test.countSuffixHash()
    test.countEven()
    test.countOdd()
    let evenArray = test.evenCount
    let oddArray = test.oddCount
    var even = 0
    var odd = 0
    test.prefixHash
    test.suffixHash
    for i in evenArray {
        even+=i
    }
    for i in oddArray {
        odd+=i
    }
    return (even+odd)-count
}

answer(str: "abbbadadfdaflpfewlpwflp")
```

i try use operators &* &- &+ and 
I got rid of the problem but now it works incorrect
whether it is possible to avoid that something else
or I do not correctly use the swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try use Int64 (-x to x) but must UInt64 ((x to x)without negative numbers)